# How do I find the standard library function I need?

Tags: emacs, apropos

I am a beginner with Elisp development, and am starting to get the hang of the syntax and data types, but I find it cumbersome to find standard library functions when I need them. They are not systematically named, so I can’t assume that for example a buffer handling function always begins with the word buffer. What I usually do is to google, and eventually find the answer, and then return to Emacs. But there must be a more efficient way to search the standard library from within Emacs, right? Which not only searches the function names, but also their documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for `apropos`. There are functions like `command-apropos`, `apropos-user-option` etc to limit the scope of what is being searched.

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Apropos.html

The real killer is `apropos-documentation` which searches for a match anywhere in a doc string on the keyword you specify; but it's understandably slow.